# Access mode from webpack-dev-server

Tags: webpack, config, webpack-dev-server, mode

Is there a possible way to access the mode of a webpack-dev-server? I want to change the login screen of my webapp depending on the mode.

Production -> normal login procedure;
Development -> no password needed;

I know, there are two ways to specify the mode:

1. in the webpack.config.js
2. via console like "webpack-dev-server --mode development

I hope this is possible :)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object to your bundle using the `DefinePlugin`.

https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/

For example:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  PRODUCTION: JSON.stringify(PRODUCTION === true)
});
```

Then anywhere in your application:

```
console.log(PRODUCTION);
```